# Domain account problem in Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003-r2

I have two Dell servers. One is DC and the other is a member server.

It was working fine a few days before I had a problem when I was logging in a member server with the domain administrator account. It doesn't have permission to install anything. Even when I create a new domain admin account the same thing happens.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check Group Policy on your domain to ensure there is no policy preventing installations that's being applied to your member server.
2. Verify that 'Domain Admins' group is a member of the local administrator group on the server.
3. If UAC is enabled on the member server, start your installations with right click -> Run as administrator.
4. Verify that Enhanced IE Security Configuration is not blocking the content you wish to install.